# Updating package in Xamarin imports many system.* dlls

Tags: c#, xamarin, nuget

I have been using SQLite PCL in my project for a long time now, and I haven't updated it because it usually creates more problems than it solves

Unfortunatelly I had to upgrade to the latest version because the package I am now using (about 8 months old) has major problems which I hope will be fixed with the latest version

When I update the nuget package though , it also downloads a big number of System.* packages (like system.collections system.appcontext, system.console etc)

What is causing this behaviour? can I avoid it? I have kept Xamarin up to date so far.

This causes a big problem because it increases my apk size by 12 MB and it's already big enough as it is

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sqlite-net-pcl version 1.3 and above depends on the .NET Standard Library NuGet package which will add a lot of packages into your packages.config file but they do not add any assemblies to the project.

If you want to avoid this you can update to version 1.2.1 instead which does not depend on the .NET Standard Library NuGet package. Whether this makes a difference to your apk file size you would have to see.

Comment: yes this seems to be it, using 1.2.1 seems to not add any extra libraries and keeps the size of my apk the same, thank you